# Is there a REST client for the ESP8266 that works with authentication?

Tags: arduino, esp8266

I have a RESTful API that I want to get a value from:

```
192.168.1.50/rest/vars/get/1/12
```

Which should returns some JSON.  The problem is this API requires authentication.  I've been able to use this [client](https://github.com/DaKaZ/esp8266-restclient) which I can do basic gets however it doesn't appear to work with authentication.

I've tried using the same client with:

```
username:password@192.168.1.50/rest/vars/get/1/12
```

but that doesn't work.  Are there any other clients available?

ETA:  I should note that `username:password@192.168.1.50/rest/vars/get/1/12` does work when called from an incognito browser, so it should be possible to make the call from the ESP8266.

Comment: We need more info. Start a packet capturer like Wireshark on your server and observe the HTTP messages. Specifically compare the requests of your browser to what the ESP does. What authentication does the JSON API need, HTTP Basic Authentication or Digest Authentication? Do you use the `RestClient::setHeader()` function to do basic auth? If it Digest Authentication, it's a little bit more complex to implement.

Comment: there's an "Authorization" demo arduino sketch under Examples>ESP8266HTTPClient, no need for a lib; looks like you might just need "http://", or you can explicitly call `setAuthorization()`